# ListView not showing text on items

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to display text input from an editText and show it in a listView using an ArrayAdapter, when clicking a button, the listView does gets an item added but without the text :

here is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.blink.blink.MainActivity">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="61dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:hint="Type a quote ..  "
                android:id="@+id/quoteField" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Add Quote"
                android:id="@+id/addQuote"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:background="#f6546a"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quoteField" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quotelistView"
            android:foreground="#f6546a"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and  :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button createBtn ;
    EditText quoteField;
    ListView quotesListView;
    ArrayList<String> quotesArrayList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createBtn = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.addQuote);
        quoteField = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.quoteField);
        quotesListView = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.quotelistView);

        quotesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();



        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                quotesArrayList.add(quoteField.getText().toString());
                SetAdapter();
                quoteField.setText(" ");
            }
        });
    }


        private void SetAdapter()
        {
            ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotesArrayList);
            quotesListView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to reset the adapter everytime you change the data in the array. What you should do is keep a reference to the adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you change the data in the list

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button createBtn ;
    EditText quoteField;
    ListView quotesListView;
    ArrayList<String> quotesArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createBtn = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.addQuote);
        quoteField = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.quoteField);
        quotesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotelistView);

        quotesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotesArrayList);
        quotesListView.setAdapter(adapter);



        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                quotesArrayList.add(quoteField.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                quoteField.setText(" ");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            quotesArrayList.add(quoteField.getText().toString());
            SetAdapter(quotesArrayList);

            quoteField.setText(" ");
        }
    });
}


    private void SetAdapter(ArrayList<String> quotesArrayList)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotesArrayList);
        quotesListView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```